# Errror using the Simplipy QGIS plugin: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'selectedFeatureCount'

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am adding a raster in QGIS 2.14.1 and get this new error:

```
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'selectedFeatureCount'
```

I am not programming, just using a QGIS menu.

I am using Linux Mint 17.3. `update` and `upgrade` made recently without effects.

This error started when I installed the Simplipy plugin. Now is disabled. I would like to test it.

What could I do?

This is the complete output:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'selectedFeatureCount' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cubarro/.qgis2/python/plugins/simplipy/simplipy.py", line 274, in refresh_input_layer_list
    if selected_layer.selectedFeatureCount() > 0:
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'selectedFeatureCount'
Versión de Python: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:03:54) [GCC 4.8.2] 
Versión de QGIS: 2.14.1-Essen Essen, exported 
Ruta de Python:
/home/cubarro/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing_gpf
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/cubarro/.qgis2/python
/home/cubarro/.qgis2/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode
/home/cubarro/.qgis2//python
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools
/home/cubarro/.qgis2/python/plugins/DigitizingTools/tools
/home/cubarro/.qgis2/python/plugins/mmqgis/forms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because the plugin (in its version 0.51) does not filter out Raster layers from the QGIS ToC and lists them in its own GUI. The plugin should only deal with Vector layers, since it acts on vector geometries.

I sent a [pull request](https://github.com/albertferras/simplipy/pull/21) to the plugin's author with code to fix this problem, which was accepted and merged by him.

The author has just released a new Simplipy version ([0.52](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/simplipy/version/0.52/)), which solves the issue. Just update the plugin repository in QGIS and upgrade the plugin from there.

Don't forget to give us feedback so that we know if everything was actually fixed.

Comment: Now it is working without error messages.
Thank you Germán!